# PHP Classes, Do people use them to build a website?

Tags: php, class, class-design

After a little debate with a friend on the use of PHP classes to build a website. How are they used to create a website? and which method is best?

For example say your website was bobs flowers, would you have a bobs flowers class? Or would you use classes within a "normal" PHP setup (eg just a DB class).

How does it work? I have always just used PHP without classes however am beginning to realise how useful they can be within programming.

Comment: I use classes all the time.  Then, again, I'm kind of a classy guy.

Comment: This is _way_ too broad for Stack Overflow, and duplicates more questions than I can list. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718068/how-important-are-classes-php) for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use classes/objects when building a website.

Regarding 'best use', you could have a look at how frameworks do it. E.G. [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)